Error while reading data from MariaDB using Pyspark
I installed MariaDB & Pyspark on my local Windows machine. Using the following code, I tried connecting to MariaDB from Pyspark and copying the table data into a dataframe. But I got the following errors. I got the first error when trying to create dataframe without schema. And the second one when trying with schema. How can I solve these?
Error 1: Without schema:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (WinPc24.ht.home executor driver): java.sql.SQLDataException: value 'date' (VARSTRING) cannot be decoded as Date
at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.column.StringColumn.decodeDateText(StringColumn.java:307)

Error 2: With schema:

TypeError: DataFrameReader.jdbc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'schema'

The table info from MariaDB:
 DESC stock_prices_nyse;
 +---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field   | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | date    | date           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | symbol  | varchar(10)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | open    | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | close   | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | low     | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | high    | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | volume  | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | country | char(10)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

I was trying to copy this table data into a Pyspark dataframe and preprocess the data. After the preprocessing, I would upload the data back into the MariaDB table.
I'm using PySpark version: 3.5.1

Code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

jdbc_driver_path = "C:/Spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/mariadb-java-client-3.4.0.jar"
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName("App2-NYSE")
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jdbc_driver_path)
    .getOrCreate()
)

# Define the database properties
db_properties = {
    "driver": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/name-database1",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "pass-mariadb"
}

table_name = "stock_prices_nyse"

# Define the schema of the dataframe based on the table of MariaDB
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DateType, StringType, DecimalType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("symbol", StringType(), True),
    StructField("open", DecimalType(15, 10), True),
    StructField("close", DecimalType(15, 10), True),
    StructField("low", DecimalType(15, 10), True),
    StructField("high", DecimalType(15, 10), True),
    StructField("volume", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("country", StringType(), True)
])

# Read data from the table with the specified schema
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=db_properties["url"], table=table_name, properties=db_properties, schema=schema)
print("First 5 rows of the dataframe:\n", df.show(5))

# Read data from the table without schema
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=db_properties["url"], table=table_name, properties=db_properties)
print("First 5 rows of the dataframe:\n", df.show(5))


Can you replace the table info with show create table stock_prices_nyse (formatted). Which MariaDB Connector J version? Which MariaDB server version?


show create table stock_prices_nyse;
| Table             | Create Table
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| stock_prices_nyse | CREATE TABLE stock_prices_nyse (
date date DEFAULT NULL,
symbol varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
open decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
close decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
low decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
high decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
volume int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
country char(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci |

1 row in set (0.002 sec)

Version:
Same as mentioned in the jdbc_driver_path variable. Spark (3.5.1) & MariaDB Connector J (3.4.0) version.
MariaDB version:

mariadb -V
mariadb from 11.4.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 3fca5ed772fb75e3e57c507edef2985f8eba5b12

